# How to use wkhtmltopdf (docker) in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, docker, wkhtmltopdf

For some reasons, I couldn't install wkhtmltopdf directly on my system, I am trying to install an wkhtmltopdf docker instead, I have tried Surnet/docker-wkhtmltopdf. I also writing an API in spring boot to convert html to pdf file. Whenever I need to convert a html file to a pdf file, I have to run a command like this.

```
        File tempFolder = new File("path/to/tempFolder"); 
        File tempHtmlFile = new File(tempFolder, "input.html");
        File tempPdfFile = new File(tempFolder, "output.pdf"); 
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
        command.add("docker");
        command.add("run");
        command.add("--rm");
        command.add("-v");
        command.add(tempFolder.getAbsolutePath() + ":/data");
        command.add("surnet/docker-alpine-wkhtmltopdf"); 
        command.add("/data/" + tempHtmlFile.getName());
        command.add("-");
        command.add(">");
        command.add(tempPdfFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
```

Every time I run the above command, it creates a container and then exits.
I want to know how can I create a container that I can run my spring boot application and the wkhtmltopdf docker, and use a simple command like wkhtmltopdf input.html output.html (which is like the command from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)
Also, Is there any different wkhtmltopdf docker that I can do like that, or any maven dependencies that I can use to convert html to pdf.